# Bluetooth socket timeout in Android. HCI_STATUS = 36 Error

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I saw many questions regarding bluetooth issues/bluetooth timeout but none of them helped me.

I am working on an app that sends and receive data to/from another bluetooth device. I am sending about 3 times per second. I know how the response should look like (a byte array like [FC ... FF]).

I am building my app based on BluetoothChat demo and I mostly changed the code in BluetoothChatService class.

What I did was to implement a new method that returns boolean(I called it boolean readWrite(byte[] data)). In this method I first write to the output stream and then read from the input stream. If writing goes fine I set a boolean to true, if reading goes fine I set another boolean to true and I convert the response byte array to a String and set this String as response. If writing/reading goes wrong my method will return false;

In my run() method of ConnectedThread I have a while(true) loop where I am using this readWrite method. I then get the String response and depending of the response I readWrite() another data.

I will post some code here so you can understand what I actually do. In this way I am trying to get rid of the socket timeouts and reset the connection if reading/writing goes wrong. I get some errors as written below but it could be my device?

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }
        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    private boolean readWrite(byte[] data) {
        byte[] read = null;
        int bytes = 0;
        String bc;
        String packet;
        boolean readPacket = false;
        boolean writing = false
        boolean reading = false; 

        try {
            // Log.d(TAG, "write to the device");
            mmOutStream.write(data);
            writing = true; 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage());
            setState(STATE_NONE);
            writing = false; 
        }
        // if writing goes ok 
        if(writing){
            read = new byte[64];
            // the response packet should be a byte array like [FC ... FF]
            while(!readPacket)
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read();
                bc = String.format("%02x", (0xFF & bytes)).toUpperCase();
                    if(bc.equalsIgnoreCase("fc"))
                    {
                        packet = "";
                        packet += bc;
                    }
                    else if(bc.equalsIgnoreCase("ff"))
                    {
                        readPacket = true;
                        packet += bc; // finish the response packet
                        Log.d(TAG, "read packet -> to UI: " + packet);
                        reading = true;
                        read = null;
                        myBluetoothService.this.setReceivedMessage(packet);
                        packet = "";
                    }
                    else{
                        packet += bc;
                    }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                reading = false;
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
        else return false;
        return (reading&&writing);
    }

    public void run() {
        setName("ConnectedThread");         
        byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
        String globalString = "";
        String requestCommand = "request";          
        buffer = requestCommand.getBytes();

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {              
            Log.d(TAG, "in the LOOP");
            if(readWrite(buffer))
            {
                // get response from the remoteDevice
                globalString = getReceivedMessage();
                String key = globalString.substring(18, 20); //substract the key pressed on the device
                int keyNum = HexString2Int(key); // convert the string to int
                switch (keyNum) {
                    case 1:
                        // code here
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        // code here
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }else {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "else JOIN - in the LOOP");
                    resetConnection();
                    Thread.currentThread().join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }               
            // pause between the loops
            try {Thread.sleep(300);Log.d(TAG, "300 sleeping time");} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        } // out of while loop
        try {
            resetConnection();
            Thread.currentThread().join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // end run()

    private void resetConnection() {
        setState(STATE_NONE);
        Log.d(TAG, "reset connection");
        if (mmInStream != null) {
            try {mmInStream.close();} catch (Exception e) {Log.d(TAG,"exception in closing inputstream - "  + e.getMessage());}
        }
        if (mmOutStream != null) {
            try {mmOutStream.close();} catch (Exception e) {Log.d(TAG,"exception in closing outputstream - " + e.getMessage());}
        }
        if (mmSocket != null) {
            try {mmSocket.close();} catch (Exception e) {Log.d(TAG,"exception in closing socket - " + e.getMessage());}
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            // close connection socket
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed - ConnectedThread cancel()", e);
        }
    }
}
```

All this works fine, but sometimes after few minutes (up to 30 minutes) I get the following errors:

```
09-20 10:44:31.270: W/bt-btif(883): dm_pm_timer expires
09-20 10:44:31.270: W/bt-btif(883): dm_pm_timer expires 0
09-20 10:44:31.290: W/bt-btif(883): proc dm_pm_timer expires
09-20 10:44:31.310: E/bt-btif(883): bta_dm_pm_btm_status  hci_status=36
```

Does anybody have any ideas why that happens ? It is really frustrating. My device is a Nexus 7 with Android 4.3, Build Number JWR66V. I tested this app on another device with android 2.3.3. The logs are different but I guess it is about the same kind of error.

Please help!

Comment: Did anyone ever find out why this was/is happening ? the workaround may work, but i'd like to know whats really going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue, and I resolved it by creating a Keep Alive Thread that transmits a byte of data on the socket every 0.3 seconds.  I believe the issue is the new Android 4.3, as I was not experiencing this issue before updating..

```
public class KeepAlive extends Thread{
private ConnectedThread connectedThread;
private final String TAG = "KeepAlive";
private volatile boolean running = true;

public KeepAlive(ConnectedThread connectedThread) {
    this.connectedThread = connectedThread;
    running = true;
}

public synchronized void run() {
    Log.d(TAG,"KeepAlive Thread starting");
    while(running) {

        try {
            wait(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        connectedThread.write('!');
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"KeepAlive Thread closing");
}

public void setRunning(boolean running) {
    this.running = running;
}
```

}

Comment: hey, it looks like the connection is more stable. but where do you start this thread? Where is the best place to setRunning(true) and to start it?

Comment: UPDATE: I did it in my service class in the public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket) method. Thank you for the solution. As far as I tested it works! Let's see for how long the connection will last.

Comment: I accepted your solution, the connection seems reliable so far. I have logs from the writing method in KeepAlive thread that shows me, that KeepAlive continues to write to the ConnectedThread but my main ConnectedThread blocks somewhere in the while(true). I can only seem to write to the outputstream from the KeepAlive thread. I am not sure why that happens. Do you have any idea? I posted my logs here: http://pastebin.com/dUjmBRQd

Comment: Can't you just set keep alive to true on the underlying socket descriptor?